Movie where car accident kills Dad and daughter, mom lives
Okay so the scene depicted a small family driving down the road. It is a couple and their daughter. The daughter is playing with dolls (or maybe one doll). As they go down the road an oncoming vehicle that has some pipe things on top crashes head on with the family's car. 
One of the pipes go through the windshield and in to the heads of the father and daughter, killing them instantly. Later the mother wakes up in the hospital and finds out her family died. 
It was definitely from the early to mid 2000s. 
I remember the daughter had dark brown hair, if that helps. It was in English and I'm pretty sure made in America. 
I think it took place during the winter, I'm pretty sure there was snow on the ground.
It was in real life and not animated.

I remember that scene! It's from The Descent (2005)
IMDB: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435625/
Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Descent

Haha yep it was! Thanks so much! It's not exactly how I remember it so my details were a little off but that's the one thanks!

Wow, I remember the ending; but I don't remember this movie having such a downer start.

@JMac probably because the start is quite disconnected from the rest of the film, it was the pipes-through-the-windshield reference that really reminded me of it
